# Deleted scenes that appear in the Edge of Tomorrow trailer

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

I'm looking for more information on what appear to be some deleted scenes from Edge of Tomorrow that appear in the official trailer (link included).

The first is at about 1:50. Cage struggling across a desolate landscape.
The second is at 1:54. Looks like Cage & Rita looking across the French landscape at sunset?

The third is the one that I am most interested in. At about 2:02 and shows a Mimic ambushing Rita in Paris (?) Another example of this scene appears in the Rita Vrataski Tribute clip (link below) at about 0:47.

And at about 2:05 we see a drop ship landing in Paris...which never happens.

I've watched the available deleted scenes on Youtube but none of these seem to be part of that collection. Does anyone know what these scenes represent or where they can be found?

[Edge of Tomorrow Official Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw61gCe2oqI&list=WL&index=19)

[Rita Vrataski Tribute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTilzRe5gJI)

Comment: You see, they filmed those scenes, released the trailer, but then something terrible happened, and thus restarted the day...

Comment: So I'm just stuck in a remnant timeline?